# Can't install .NET framework 4.0 on PC

Tags: windows-xp, .net-framework, visual-studio

We have 2 different types of computers here at college:

1. computers that anyone can use which have restricted access.
2. computers that only students that follow a computer science study can use (I'm one of those)

Now, they both have Windows XP as OS and some kind of restricted access.
I figured that it'd be a group policy since we're already Administrator on the account.
So I disabled the group policy for the computer with gpedit.msc and tried to install Visual Studio C# 2010 express, this succeeded on the type 2 PC's but it errors out constantly at .NET framework for the type 1 PC's, [this](http://pastebin.com/VQEcZDhL) is the whole log that's generated on installation of the standalone installer of .NET framework 4.0.

I've already tried cleaning up windows installer with the windows installer cleanup utility but that didn't succeed either.

Comment: have you disabled the Installer service? error  0x80070641 = ERROR_INSTALL_SERVICE_FAILURE ( The Windows Installer Service could not be accessed. This can occur if the Windows Installer is not correctly installed)

Comment: It is currently running as service. It might be inaccessible cause of security things, but the AV is off and so is Group Policy, so I'm not sure what would be causing it.

Comment: This might help (your log shows the error 0x80070641): http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/80e098d1-3466-4c6e-8ba2-ee196814b650/resolution-error-code-0x80070641?forum=exchangesvr3rdpartyappslegacy